# Highlight realtime track with google maps

Tags: android, flutter, google-maps, real-time

I'm making an app that control a drone, and I need to show its flight track and another track showing where the drone's LED were on.

The drone's track is easy. The problem is with the LED's track. Since the track width is important, I'm overlaping multiple circles (one for each location - 10 locations per second), since they have the radius property that is specified in meters.

The problem with the current approach is that the drone can make paths of 6km, but in the first 600m the app starts becoming really slow.

The problem using polylines, is that they have their width in pixels, not in meters.

How could I achieve my goal without consuming a lot of memory?

Some considerations are: the track width is important, and the drone will make a straight path most of the time, but it can make curves near waypoints.

I'm using flutter with google's official package for google maps, but any help considering native android code are welcome. This may help somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have the details on how this works, but works:

```dart
// https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/7430/what-ratio-scales-do-google-maps-zoom-levels-correspond-to
final metersPerPx = 156543.03392 *
    math.cos(currentLocation.lat * math.pi / 180) /
    math.pow(2, currentZoomLevel);
final widthInPx = widthInMeters ~/ metersPerPx;
```